# WKWebView - replace web action

Tags: objective-c, swift, wkwebview

Inside my app, I'm using the WKWebView to display a website. My goal is, when user is pressing a button on this website, I want to stop an action linked to this event and replace it with my own, natively made (custom action outside the WKWebView). I've been trying to search for any solution to fetch mentioned event but unsuccessful. What more came to my mind, if there is a way to fetch a JavaScript in WKWebView, I have a possibility to add some JS script code to this site (not to delete the action I want to block). Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First, do you have a permission to mess with this web site's behaviour? I assume you do, otherwise it is likely illegal.

Second, try using Safari Web Inspector with a device/simulator, and use the DOM tree and console tools to find out what is the HTML/javascript that is involved with this action on this site.

If you can't find what happens in HTML/JS yourself, feel free to post a new separate question on SO with your target URL, some HTML/JS code, and which link/action you want to replace. Tag the question with "javascript" and ask if it is possible to write some javascript to replace that particular action to some custom JS code.

Usually there are 2 types of actions: either it is something that provokes AJAX calls to a server API triggered by an event handler, or it is a plain HTML link that results in a web navigation. For both cases it is possible to write a JS script that overrides the action.

Finally, use [WKUserScript](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript?language=objc) to inject javascript into the page, and override the action. Use `window.webkit.messageHandlers` to send an event from your custom action to the app side. Use [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkscriptmessagehandler?language=objc) to process the event in the Objective-C or Swift code.

See an example here: http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/